# Sencha touch 2 conflicting listeners

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have listeners for html code in the following style:

```
listeners  :  {
        tap: {
            fn: function(e, del, sender) {
                console.log("you pressed A!");
            },
            element : 'element',
            delegate : '.a'
        },
        tap: {
            fn: function(e, del, sender) {
                console.log("You pressed B!");
            },
            element:'element',
            delegate : '.b'
        }
    }
```

Within listeners they both conflict and only the second one will be attached. Both of them use the name 'tap' in the same object for listeners so I assume this is the reason,

How would I fix this? (Btw this is abridged I have a couple of keyups there too), I can't attach directly to the elements because they're listeners for html code.

Comment: Just use one tap listener without any delegate and then check wherever the event comes from (probably with e.target).

Answer (score 0):

```
listeners:{
    tap: function(list, index, target, record, e, eOpts){
        var elm = Ext.get(e.target);
        if(elm.dom.className == "a"){} // or any other thing you want to check
    }
}
```

you can console it to see more info on it you can also do `elm.dom.id`